# Creation of the game world in full screen on phaser js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I create a game world In Phaser framework

```
 var game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });
```

1) Why the report of the game world does not start from the left upper edge, but as if on the coordinates `x = 10` and `y = 10`?

2) How to make the whole screen game world? (As I did above `window.innerWidth` `window.innerHeight` have to scroll a bit, but you need to scroll!)

In Phaser there are:

```
this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
this.scale.pageAlignHorisontally = true; 
this.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
```

but from them the effect is the same (scrolling remains, and the beginning of the game world is not from the left upper edge)

Explain, please!

Answer (score 0):

A solution was found. It was necessary to add the following style in the main document html

```
<style>
    body {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        background: black;
    }
</style>
```